# SQL Server domain user is admin but want to reduce ability to run some sp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wonder if this is possible.
Situation is that we have sql server 2000 and 2008 r2, we have some users who have elevated roles on production domain, however, there are some stored procedures which we want to deny access for these admin users.
I have tried to use deny permissions but it seems like domain user role permissions always take precedence..
Is there a way to do something like this as I mentioned?

Comment: If you've trusted someone to be domain admin, then you basically have to assume that they own all of the servers, and everything that's on them. You can try all the DENY tricks you want, there will be ways for them to circumvent them. Let it be known that there are consequences for running things they're not supposed to, and implement auditing.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that, but still thought may be, just may be there is a way to stop an admin user from accessing stored proc, may be some type of trigger? at some level of system in sql server...what I am thinking is that sql server system must know when a sp is called, and I am sure it logs it somewhere and if I can put some type of watch there, I can control this...?

Comment: There is no "before execute procedure trigger" - like I said, you can `DENY` execute on a stored procedure, but if the person is determined, they can get around it. Why do you have domain admins that you don't trust?

Comment: I think its not that we don't trust, this is a legal requirement that there are some sps which, if used have to be logged, therefore I am trying to find a way to know when those sps are called, so that I can create some type of log entry. We can not turn on full logging on sql server nor run profiler for this purpose as both are not suitable for extremely active sql server. So my logic is simple, if some how I can put some sort of trigger which allows me to tell when a sp is called, then I cal log it, Hope it clarifies...and you can make some suggestion, as I have none..:-)

Comment: Again, there is no "a procedure was executed" trigger. Why not just log within the procedure?

Comment: Can not do that, reason being its 3rd party class that is called using sp_OACreate +sp_OAMethod with its clsid...so you can see that I can not write any type of logging, all I can do is potentially find out when sp_OACreate and sp_OAMethod are called for that clsid..